# Can you automate an ETL to dashboard pipeline using python/SQL/R and PowerBI?

Tags: python, powerbi, etl

Here's what I want to automate:

1. get data from an API,
2. do some cleaning and wrangling in python,
3. save as Excel,
4. **load to PowerBI and**
5. **produce very simple dashboard**.

I've been searching for ages on Microsoft forums and here to find out if there's a way to run PowerBI via a script, like a Powershell script, for instance. I'm comfortable with writing a script for doing the first 3 steps, but I have not been able to find a solution for steps 4-5. It has to be loaded to PowerBI because that's what clients are most familiar with. The ideal result would be a script that I can then package as an executable file, send to a non-technical person so they can run it at their own leisure.

Although I'd prefer a solution in python, if it's possible in SQL or R, I'd also be very happy. I've tried all the in-PowerBI options for using python scripts, but I have found them limited and difficult to use. I've packaged all my ETL functions into a py script, then imported it to PowerBI and ran functions therein, but it's still not really fully automated, and wouldn't land well with non-technical folks. Thanks in advance! (I am working on PC, PowerBI Desktop)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you want to create dashboard programmatically or do you want to create one manually and just refresh underlying data?

Comment: And do you want power bi to run this python pipeline or do you have an external python interpreter to do that job? Power BI is not designed to do that. You would need another machine to do the processing, upload the Excel file to the location accessible by pbi service and the user rest api to refresh your dataset. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/refreshdataset

Comment: Thanks, @W.B., I should've made myself clearer: 1. main goal is to create dashboard programmatically; 2. I'm open to any way of having the pipeline run, whether through an external py interpreter or powerBI (granted, I'm not optimistic about finding ways to do it through the latter means)

Comment: Just so that I understanad, why do you want to create dashboard programmatically? Is the dataset going to be different every time? Is the report/dashboard going to look different every (other) time?